# Catch the last update of component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs can I know the last time the component was updated after I took the action, then it won't update anymore?

Comment: Hi James, componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). The problem I  mention about updated component

Comment: Sorry, I meant ComponentDidUpdate()

Comment: Yep, componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. But I mean is there any way to know it's is last time updated. Sorry if i wasted  your time